# Iterating keys in NSMapTable retains the weak values forever

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use `NSMapTable` to weakly store some object instances, indexed by a string.

(My use case is to store some cached metadata about remote servers, and have every active client share that metadata. When there are no clients connecting to that specific server anymore, the metadata should be removed from memory.)

This is all working fine, as long as I never iterate over the keys. It seems like, that if I have iterated over a specific key, the value for that key will never be released.

I've managed to reduce it down to a small code snippet that shows the problem:

```
import Foundation

class Foobar {
    let id: String
    init(_ id: String) { print("init \(id)"); self.id = id }
    deinit { print("deinit \(id)") }
}

let map = NSMapTable<NSString, Foobar>(keyOptions: .strongMemory, valueOptions: .weakMemory)

func addSome() {
    let a = Foobar("a")
    let b = Foobar("b")
    let c = Foobar("c")

    map.setObject(a, forKey: "a")
    map.setObject(b, forKey: "b")
    map.setObject(c, forKey: "c")

    let e = map.keyEnumerator()
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
}

addSome()

print(map.object(forKey: "a") ?? "nil")
print(map.object(forKey: "b") ?? "nil")
print(map.object(forKey: "c") ?? "nil")
```

If I comment out one or more of the `e.nextObject()` calls, the values for the corresponding keys will be properly released, and `map.object(forKey:)` will properly return `nil`.

Do I have to manually clean up the enumerator after I'm done with it in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the map enumerator returns “autoreleased” objects – these are released when the scope of the current autorelease pool is left.

In iOS or macOS applications that would happen automatically when program control returns to the main event loop. In any case, you can use a local [autorelease pool](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html)

```
autoreleasepool {
    let e = map.keyEnumerator()
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
    print("nextObject: \(e.nextObject() ?? "nil")")
}
```

to have the objects released immediately after the enumeration.

*Remark:* `NSEnumerator` is a `Sequence`, so that you can enumerate it with a for-loop:

```
autoreleasepool {
    let e = map.keyEnumerator()
    for case let key as String in e {
        print(key)
    }
}
```